# Using Mean Value Theorem x

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\left[ 0,1\right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f\left( 0\right) =0$ and $\left| f'\left( x\right) \right| \leq 1$ for all $x$ in $\left( 0,1\right)$. Prove that $-x\leq f\left( x\right) \leq x$ for all $x$ in $\left[ 0,1\right]$.

Proof-trying. We will use the mean value theorem. By the mean value theorem and assumption, there is a $c$ in $\left( a,b\right)$ such that

$\left| f'\left( c\right) \right| =\left| \dfrac {f\left( 1\right) -f\left( 0\right) } {1-0}\right| =\left| f\left( 1\right) \right| \leq 1
$. Hence, $-1\leq f\left( 1\right) \leq 1$. **So, what should I do?**

Comment: It's equivalent to proving $$\left|\frac {f\left(x\right) -f\left( 0\right) } {x-0}\right| \le 1.$$

Comment: @GNUSupporter by the mean value theorem, can we say that there is a $c$ in $(a,b)$ $f\left( c\right) =\dfrac {f\left( x\right) -f\left( 0\right) } {x-0}
$?

Comment: No, because you missed a ' on the LHS.  $$f'(c) = \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$

Comment: @GNUSupporter Then, why did you say $\left| \dfrac {f\left( x\right) -f\left( 0\right) } {x-0}\right| \leq 1$?

Comment: Due to your edit: $\left| f'\left( x\right) \right| \leq 1\forall x \in (0,1)$

Comment: So we have $|f'(c)|\le1$, and we're done

Comment: @GNUSupporter I.e., from this, $\lim _{x\rightarrow 0^+}\dfrac {f\left( x\right) -f\left( 0^+\right) } {x-0^+}\leq 1$, right?

Comment: @GNUSupporter Can you write clearly as answer?

Comment: Why take limit?  We don't need limit $x \to 0^+$ here since we are proving this for *all* $x$ in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter I used definition of derivative.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Again, can you write clearly as answer here?

Comment: I've put the above arguments into a solution.  Plz check.

Answer (score 3):

In response to OP's comments, I convert my comments into an answer.

It suffices to show that $$\left|\frac {f\left(x\right) -f\left( 0\right) } {x-0}\right| \le 1 \quad\forall x\in[0,1].$$

Since we have the continuity of $f$ on the *closed* interval $[0,1]$ and the differentiability on the *open* interval $(0,1)$, we can apply the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) to conclude that for *each* $x \in [0,1]$, there exists $c \in (0,x)$ so that
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}.$$

Since $c \in (0,x) \subseteq (0,1)$, $|f'(c)| \le 1$, so we're done.

Comment: Very courteous of you to do for the OP. (+1)

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your comment and +1

Comment: You showed that $\left| f'\left( c\right) \right| \leq 1$ but you didn't show $\left| f'\left( x\right) \right| \leq x$ for all $x$ in $\left[ 0,1\right]$?

Comment: @Kahler Why do I need this?  The question asks for $$-x\leq f\left( x\right) \leq x\iff|f(x)|\le x\quad\forall x \in [0,1].$$

Comment: @GNUSupporter Yes, the question asks for this. But, you only showed $\left| f\left( c\right) \right| \leq 1$ for $c\in(0,x)$. Is it enough? Why? I couldn't be convinced.

Comment: @Kahler No, I've never attempted to show the function *value* of $c$ would be bounded by one (and I *don't think* that's relevant).  Instead, I used the *hypothesis* that the derivative of $f$ on $(0,x)$ is bounded by one. Symbolically, their difference is a dash in between $f$ and $c$.  (i.e. $|f(c)| \le 1$ vs $|f\color{red}{'}(c)| \le 1$)  You may view the linked Wiki page to see the exact statement of MVT. (This is *not* required in a solution on math.SE though)  Don't worry if you aren't convinced!  Those who upvoted are too smart :xp  You *couldn't* be convinced, and I hope now you *can*.